# Import issue in Python | from Splitwise.models.bill import Bill ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Splitwise'

Tags: python, import

currently I'm using python version 3.9.1

```
Splitwise

       models

                  __init__.py

                 -----bill.py

                         -------class Bill(object):
                                   ***code here***
                 -----user.py
                 -----group.py
      services

                ------__init__.py

      controlers

               ------__init__.py

     __init__.py

      driver.py
```

**** and every directory have **init**.py file still I'm facing this issue.
anyone please tell me where I've made mistake .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: It seems that you dont have the module Splitwise installed

Comment: Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Open `Command Prompt` on your PC. Then type `pip install splitwise` and run the command. It will install Splitwise SDK library on your PC. After that, your code will run fine.

Comment: File "c:\Users\1434743\Project\OOD\splitwise\driver.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .controllers.group_controller import GroupController
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Please can you send some starting lines of your code which contains import statement

Comment: import sys
from .bill_service_interface import BillServiceInterface
from splitwise.models.bill import Bill
class BillService(BillServiceInterface):